# R: How do I c() nested character vectors grouped by another column?

Tags: r, purrr

I have strings containing enumerations of words grouped under word type. The example below only has one type for simplicity's sake.

```
ka = tibble(
  words = c('apple, orange', 'pear, apple, plum'),
  type = 'fruit'
)
```

I want to find out the number of UNIQUE words per type.

I figured I would split the character vectors,

```
ka = ka %>% 
  mutate(
    word_list = str_split(words, ', ')
  )
```

and then bind the columns per group. The end result would be

```
c(
ka$word_list[[1]],
ka$word_list[[2]],
)
```

Then I can unique these vectors and get their length.

I don't know how to bind columns together, grouped by a separate column. I could do this with an ugly loop within a loop, but there must be a map/apply solution as well, following the logic of:

```
ka %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(
    biglist = map(word_list, ~ c(.)), # this doesn't work, obviously
    biglist_unique = map(biglist, ~ unique(.)),
    biglist_length = map(biglist_unique, ~ length(.))
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
ka %>% 
  mutate(words = strsplit(as.character(words), ",")) %>% 
  unnest(words) %>% 
  mutate(words = gsub(" ","",words)) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(number =  n_distinct(words),
            words = paste0(unique(words), collapse =' '))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  type  number words                 
  <chr>  <int> <chr>                 
1 fruit      4 apple orange pear plum
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option for you. First we collapse the vectors, then we map out what you're looking for. Note that we have to trim off the whitespace to get the proper unique words.

```
library(tidyverse)

ka %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(all_words = paste(words, collapse = ",")) %>%
  mutate(biglist = str_split(all_words, ",") %>% map(., ~str_trim(.x, "both")),
         biglist_unique = map(biglist, ~.x[unique(.x)]),
         biglist_length = map_dbl(biglist_unique, length))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   type  all_words                       biglist   biglist_unique biglist_length
#>   <chr> <chr>                           <list>    <list>                  <dbl>
#> 1 fruit apple, orange,pear, apple, plum <chr [5]> <chr [4]>                   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use tidy data principles and the `tidyr` package.

```
ka = ka %>% 
  mutate(
    word_list = str_split(words, ', ')
  )

ka %>%
  # If you need to maintain information about each row you can create an index
  # mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
  # unnest the wordlist to get one word per row
  unnest(word_list) %>%
  # Only keep unique words per group
  group_by(type) %>%
  distinct(word_list, .keep_all = FALSE) %>% # if you need to maintain row info .keep_all = TRUE
  summarise(n_unique = n())
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# type  n_unique
#     <chr>    <int>
#   1 fruit        4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do using [`separate_rows`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html):

```
ka %>% 
  separate_rows(words, sep = ', ') %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise(word_c = n_distinct(words))
```